# When accessing a property with a cast, the set method is called. Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Tags: laravel

I have a Product class with a cast for the price property:

```
protected $casts = [
    'price' => MoneyDecimalCast::class . ':RUB,true',
];
```

In the set method of this cast, I have:

```
dd("Run");
```

Then, in my controller, I have:

```
$test = Product::query()->get()->first();
dd($test->price);
```

The Run message is not shown, but if I modify the code to:

```
$test = Product::query()->get()->first();
dd($test->price, $test->price);
```

The set method is called, and Run is displayed.

If I return the list of products in a resource, the set method is called every time the price is accessed.

Is there a way to prevent the set method from being called when accessing a property with a cast?

upd: TestCast

```
class TestCast  implements CastsAttributes
{

    public function get($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
       return new Product();
    }

    public function set($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        dd('Run');
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't using getters do the same and avoid the problem you are in?

Comment: You need to show us what that `MoneyDecimalCast` is doing, full code

Comment: @matiaslauriti 

    public function get($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }

        return Money::parse($value, $this->getCurrency($attributes), $this->forceDecimals);
    }

    public function set($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        dd("Run");
    }

Comment: Add that code on the question please, not as a comment

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have added a test CastsAttributes class. It works the same as MoneyDecimalCast. It is important to return an object (any) from the get method.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: Same problem...and solution?